# I want to replace \ with \\\\ using sed

Tags: sed, special-characters

I have tried using sed to read `\`.
Unable to read `\` and replace it with `\\\\`.
I want to replace single `\` with 4 `\\\\`.

Comment: Did you try this ? `echo '\' | sed 's/\\/\\\\\\\\/g'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of backslashes needed for escaping regex backslash on the command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32260/number-of-backslashes-needed-for-escaping-regex-backslash-on-the-command-line)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show us your attempt, as that will help with writing better answers.

Answer (score 3):

In a single quoted substitution, use 2 backslash for each literal backslash.

```
echo '\' | sed 's/\\/\\\\\\\\/'
```

In a double quoted substitution, you need 4 backslashes for each literal backslash, as the shell interprets each `\\` as a backslash.

```
echo '\' | sed "s/\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/"
```

Comment: I used the sed -i 's/\\/\\\\\\\\/g' filename. It worked. Thanks.

Comment: "Thanks" on StackExchange = Upvote / Accept.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
sed 's/[\]/&&&&/'
```

Within `[...]`, which is an expression that matches a single character from the set within the brackets, each `\` is literal, so there is no need to escape it (if you use single quotes around the expression; with double quotes, you still have to escape the backslash).

Each of the four `&` in the replacement string will be replaced by whatever was matched by the regular expression.

Alternatively, if `[\]` feels weird,

```bsh
sed 's/\\/&&&&/'
```