# solution to insert a special character using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to replace `&` by `\&` in a tex file.
I'm using `sed -i "s/ & / \\\& /g" bibfile.bib;`
However, the result in the file is `\ &` and not `\&` as I expect.
Any help would be welcome,
Marc

Comment: Related: [Number of backslashes needed for escaping regex backslash on the command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32260/number-of-backslashes-needed-for-escaping-regex-backslash-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Using double quotes means you have only extra layer of escaping to do for backslash. Use single quotes instead (assuming you're using a Bourne-like shell).

Answer (score 5):

In Bourne-like shells, using double quotes means you have one extra layer of escaping to do for backslash as `\` is used inside double quotes to escape `` ` ``, `"`, `$` and itself  and do line continuation.

Use single quotes instead.

There are also more shells that support `'...'` as a quoting operator than some supporting `"..."`.

So:

```
sed -i 's/ & / \\\& /g' bibfile.bib
```

calls `sed` with `sed`, `-i`, `s/ & / \\\& /g`¹ and `bibfile.bib` as four separate arguments.

To send the same arguments using double quotes, you'd need at least:

```
sed -i "s/ & / \\\\\&" bibfile.bib
```

Where the first two pairs of `\` become one `\` each and `\&` stays `\&`.

```
sed -i "s/ & / \\\\\\&" bibfile.bib
```

Would also work and be cleaner IMO making it more explicit that you want 3 backslashes to be passed to `sed`, each inserted as `\\` within double quotes.

You could also do:

```
sed -i 's/ \(& \)/ \\\1/g' bibfile.bib
```

Or:

```
sed -Ei 's/ (& )/ \\\1/g' bibfile.bib
```

Your:

> ```
> sed -i 's/ & / \\\& /g' bibfile.bib
> ```

Actually passes `sed`, `-i`, `s/ & / \\& /g` and `bibfile.bib` as argument to `sed`, which it interprets as prefixing each `" & "` with `" \"` and suffixing with `" "`.

---

For completeness, in some other shells:

#### csh/tcsh

in csh/tcsh, `\` is not special within `'...'` nor `"..."` (except to escape `!` for history expansion).

So `sed -i "s/ & / \\\& /g" bibfile.bib` and `sed -i 's/ & / \\\& /g' bibfile.bib` would both work there.

#### fish

In fish, `\` is also special inside `'...'`, so you'd need either:

```
sed -i "s/ & / \\\\\\& /g" bibfile.bib
```

Or

```
sed -i 's/ & / \\\\\\& /g' bibfile.bib
```

The latter still preferred in the general case as there are fewer characters to escape within.

#### rc

rc has only one form of quoting: `'...'` (not `"..."`, nor `\` nor `$'...'` nor `$"..."`)

```
sed -i 's/ & / \\\& /g' bibfile.bib
```

only there.

See [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for more details as to what characters are special and how to escape/quote them in various shells.

---

<sup>¹ and for `sed`, in the replacement part of its `s/pattern/replacement/flags` command, the `\\` is interpreted as a backslash and `\&` as a literal `&` as opposed to its special meaning of expanding to what was matched.</sup>